Projection onto a real subspace within a complex vector space
Given a complex vector space $V$, choose a finite set of vectors from $V$:
$$S = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}.$$
Now consider the following "real subspace" of V:
$$R = \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i: a_i \text{ is a real number}\}$$
Given a vector $w$ in $V$, what is the vector $u \in R$ that minimizes $||u-w||_2$, where $||.||_2$ is induced by the complex inner product?
If $R$ is a complex subspace, the solution is simple. $u$ is simply is the projection of $w$ onto $R$.
But what happens if $R$ is a real space?
Is there a good geometric interpretation of this problem?

It's still the orthogonal projection of $w$ onto $R$. The result holds for any real Hilbert space, and complex Hilbert spaces are in particular real Hilbert spaces. (The real inner product is the real part of the complex inner product.) Of course, since $R$ is only a real subspace, the orthogonal projection is only real-linear instead of complex-linear.

I'm confused by which inner product to use for the orthogonal projection, which you alluded to. The $||.||_2$ should be from the complex inner product. But the "orthogonal projection onto R" only makes sense if one views $V$ as a real vector space and project onto $R$ using the real inner product, which as you said, is different from the complex inner product. The projection onto $R$ seems to minimize $||.||_2$ induced by the real inner product. I really want to minimize the $||.||_2$ defined by the complex inner product. It seems that the solution you suggested minimizes the wrong distance?

If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a complex inner product, then $\text{Re}(\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is a real inner product, and the two inner products induce the exact same norm - $\langle h, h \rangle$ is already real (in fact non-negative), so $\text{Re}(\langle h, h\rangle) = \langle h, h\rangle$. Therefore, they induce the same distance as well.

Oh, right! You are 100% correct. I didn’t appreciate the fact that ||.||_2 is the same whether it’s induced by the real or the complex inner product. Thanks very much!

That would be a good answer to the post.
